# Why can't I view --> page-source of an iframe? How can I make iframe contents viewable?

Tags: html, css, iframe

When I load a page that has an iframe, often (perhaps always) I can't see the content of that iframe using the browser's View --> PageSource menu choice. Two questions:

1. Why should the iframe's content be unviewable?
2. How can I change my html or css so that it ***is*** viewable?

**EDIT:** @diEcho and @JohnP answered the second question (thanks, guys!) but the first question remains:

How come the iframe's content is unviewable in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: The content of the iframe isn't unviewable. Anyone with a modern browser can do the things I mentioned to view the code. Since and iframe is like a browser withing a browser, that behavior is needed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Firefox, you can right click inside the iframe and select `This Frame -> View Source` and you can view the source of the iframe.

And in Chrome, it's `View Frame Source`

Answer (score 2):

if using firefox then install [Web developer addon](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)  ..there is option to see page source of specific iframe...

HAPPY TO HELP

Comment: Such a Easy way to do this, was at it for hours. Thx a lot mate.